# Jquery syntax error if

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I cant seem to figure out whats wrong with my if, can anybody help me please

```
$("#tablet_windows").on('click', function(){
    $( ".demo-divs .span3" ).each(function( index ) {
        var that = $(this);
        if(!that.hasClass('opacity')) {
            //this line is wrong
            that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0;  { 
            that.toggleClass('opacity');
            that.find('.rating').toggleClass('opacity');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the if is missing

Comment: Are you finding any error firebug console ?

Comment: Why is there a braces at the end of the find line? `.length == 0;  { ` ?? @Patric you're issue currently is that you're giving us very little information to help you out. Please try and update your answer before it's closed.

Comment: @Zenith It's basic. Maybe it's too localized. But you need to code to learn. And everybody sometimes makes a basic error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `if` is missing :

Change

```
that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0;  { //this line is wrong
```

to

```
if (that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0) {
```

Comment: OT, but why did you make this a community wiki?

Comment: @Dogbert I really should prepare a clear answer for that question I'm often asked... For now it will be *"Err... It's not forbidden, is it ?"*.

Comment: @Dogbert , knowing dystroy, he often answers questions like this that are pretty low quality (syntax errors, basic stuff) as community wiki. He does so because he does not want to gain rep for these type of answers but he still thinks OP deserves a clear/concise solution. Often users, in bad taste, hop on these sort of questions after an experienced user has said what's wrong in a comment and answer it, these sort of thing prevents it.

Comment: In fact I know a few other users who would have answered with a comment instead of a CW answer, that's probably about the same.

Answer (score 0):

change this line: (*missing if*)

```
that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0;  {
```

should look like this -

```
$("#tablet_windows").on('click', function(){
    $( ".demo-divs .span3" ).each(function( index ) {
        var that = $(this);
        if(!that.hasClass('opacity')) {
            if(that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0)  { //this line is wrong
            that.toggleClass('opacity');
            that.find('.rating').toggleClass('opacity');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tablet_windows").on('click', function(){
$( ".demo-divs .span3" ).each(function( index ) {
    var that = $(this);
    if(!that.hasClass('opacity')) {
     if(that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0)  {
        that.toggleClass('opacity');
        that.find('.rating').toggleClass('opacity');
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(that.find('.attributes-container .tablet_windows').length == 0)
{
            that.toggleClass('opacity');
            that.find('.rating').toggleClass('opacity');
            }
```